# How to output model's objects from index.php?

Tags: yii

I have a model TaxiDriver.php, controller TaxiDriverController and view pages for it. I want to  display data from this model in my main page. I tried to create an instance of TaxiRider.php, but then I don't know how to read the data from object. I used findAll() for it, but outout is not readable

Comment: I would highly recommend you to read Yii's documentation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load the model in your SiteController (Assuming you are using that for your main page.)

```
// SiteController.php
public function actionIndex()
{
    // Find the driver or drivers you want to display data from.
    // Nothing stops you from doing this directly in the view.
    // (But separating business logic from your presentational code can be a good idea.)
    $taxiDriver = TaxiDriver::model()->findByPk(1);
    $taxiDrivers = TaxiDriver::model()->findAll();


    // Render the page and send in the data 
    $this->render( 'index', 
        [
            'driver'=>$taxiDriver, 
            'drivers'=>$taxiDrivers
        ] 
    );
}
```

Then you can access your driver data like this:

```
// view/site/index.php
<h1>
<?php echo $driver->name; ?>   // Assuming there is a name field in your TaxiDriver.
</h1>
```

And if you used findAll() you'll have an array of ActiveRecord instead:

```
foreach ($drivers as $driver) {
    echo $driver->name;
}
```

If you want to display a list of drivers, look into the [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) and [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) widgets.

I know how it is - You want to get straight to the point and there never seems to be enough examples of the exact thing you want to do. But it really is all there in the documentation. Take your time and read it carefully and things will pick up speed from there.

Answer (score 0):

change your default controller from site to taxi driver in main.php